# Reversed Inset a face of a mesh

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces, subdivision-surface

I'm not a pro at 3d modeling, but i can do more and more everyday. There is one thing I do hate is when i need to make like a window or door frame out of a hole in a cube mesh and having to reface everything so no face overlapping.

Is there a way to inset a face of a mesh outside of the bounderies of that face and do not overlay new faces with faces next to the inseted face?

I would like something like that with the red line.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red line you want would create n-gons.
But if you build the frame differently, you can simply add a loopcut.

[image]

Comment: thx for fast reply, but i dont want to make the door hole larger to red dots, i want more vertices to make a door frame(in the case of my example). I could just union a frame directly, but if i can get like my example where the system add vertices and edges like inset does. i want to include the red vertices and edge I draw on my example.

Comment: Oh, I see :). The red line you want would create n-gons. But if you build the frame differently, you can simply add a loopcut - https://imgur.com/a/fyjMiXO

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted! thank you very much!!